# Photos: Export all images without downloading them?

Tags: icloud, photos, nas, photos.app

I just started using iCloud Photo Library. I uploaded all images using Photos for Mac. Now, I enabled the "Optimize Mac Storage" option, so the full-resolution files are not stored on my Mac. However, I'd like to keep a local backup of all photos stored in iCloud Photo Library (and therefore in Photos for Mac) on my NAS. There is an option to export images.

**Is it possible to export all images without downloading them first?**
I'd like Photos for Mac to download all images from iCloud Photo Library directly to my NAS, so that they are at not downloaded/stored on my Mac during the export process.

Comment: Please close the question or maybe explain how it didn't answer your question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a web browser by logging in to [iCloud.com](http://icloud.com) and accessing your photos there. Photos get downloaded to your default download location (which usually is `~/Downloads`), so change this in Safari Settings first to point to the NAS.